# Working socket.io demo getting error message with

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've been looking for a working demo of socket.io that does not use Express.js, why doesn't this example work:

server:

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', client => {
  client.on('event', data => { /* … */ });
  client.on('disconnect', () => { /* … */ });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

client:

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io("http://localhost");
</script>
```

This gives the error:
polling-xhr.js:157 GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NwWVGV9 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works:

server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler(req, res) {
    var url;
    if (req.url == "/") {
        url = "/index.html";
    } else {
        url = req.url;
    }
    fs.readFile(__dirname + url, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id + ' disconnect ('+ socket.client.conn.transport.constructor.name +')');
    });
});
```

client:

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```